Trying to sort in alphabetical order of last name but needs to be formatted ID, first name, last name
No matter what I try with cut, awk, sed, or grep, it orders by ID first only then last name then first name when it should go in order of last name so it instead should look like
  f132b02: Kiara Acevedo
  f132a01: Caleb Barn

but instead it orders it by ID and not alphabetical last name and output looks like this
f132a01: Barn, Caleb
f132b02: Acevedo, Kiara

the information from the folder I'm retrieving the information is extracted from "~/Homework4/etc/passwd" and is trying to order the IDs below
f132a01:Barn  Caleb
f132a02:Casey  Nathan
f132a03:Sanchez  Ana
f132a04:Thomas  Jeff
f132a05:Cavhill  Jared
f132b01:Johnson  Andrew
f132b02:Acevedo  Kiara
f132b03:Felaccio  Steven
f132b05:Blotner  Sam
f132b06:Pereira  Brian

The code I've been trying is down below:
INPUT:
cut -d: -f1,5 /etc/passwd | grep f132 | \
username, first name, and last name
sed -E 's/(.*), (.*) (.*)/\1 \2 \3/' | \
sort -k3

echo

count=$(cut -d: -f1,5 /etc/passwd | grep f132 | wc -l)
echo "Number of students in the class: $count"

OUTPUT:
    f132a01:Barn  Caleb
    f132a02:Casey  Nathan
    f132a03:Sanchez  Ana
    f132a04:Thomas  Jeff
    f132a05:Cavhill  Jared
    f132b01:Johnson  Andrew
    f132b02:Acevedo  Kiara
    f132b03:Felaccio  Steven
    f132b05:Blotner  Sam
    f132b06:Pereira  Brian


Edit the question and add some of the sample text so that there is an idea of what you are trying to sort.

Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Add the entire lines of of /etc/passwd to the question in order to verify what fields have contents and clarify if they all have the same information in each field. If that is from /etc/passwd, then there is more than that.

sort -k2 -t:   <- "-t, --field-separator=SEP   ;
use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition"

It sounds from your description like you might just be trying to sort this input:
$ cat file
f132a01:Barn  Caleb
f132a02:Casey  Nathan
f132a03:Sanchez  Ana
f132a04:Thomas  Jeff
f132a05:Cavhill  Jared
f132b01:Johnson  Andrew
f132b02:Acevedo  Kiara
f132b03:Felaccio  Steven
f132b05:Blotner  Sam
f132b06:Pereira  Brian

by name in which case all you need is:
$ sort -t':' -k2 file
f132b02:Acevedo  Kiara
f132a01:Barn  Caleb
f132b05:Blotner  Sam
f132a02:Casey  Nathan
f132a05:Cavhill  Jared
f132b03:Felaccio  Steven
f132b01:Johnson  Andrew
f132b06:Pereira  Brian
f132a03:Sanchez  Ana
f132a04:Thomas  Jeff

but you also say "but needs to be formatted ID, first name, last name" so then maybe what you want is this:
$ awk -F'[: ]+' -v OFS=',' '{print $1, $3, $2}' file | sort -t',' -k3
f132b02,Kiara,Acevedo
f132a01,Caleb,Barn
f132b05,Sam,Blotner
f132a02,Nathan,Casey
f132a05,Jared,Cavhill
f132b03,Steven,Felaccio
f132b01,Andrew,Johnson
f132b06,Brian,Pereira
f132a03,Ana,Sanchez
f132a04,Jeff,Thomas


Using gawk:
 $ awk -F '[: ]+' -v OFS=","  '{
      ar[$2 FS $3 FS FNR]= $1 OFS $3 OFS $2}
      END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc";
          for(i in ar) print ar[i]}
  ' file

